# Mysql : Trigger after insert copy content into another table and delete row from triggered table

Tags: mysql, triggers

Here I want to copy the contents of X table into Y table and on the same lines I wanted to delete the row from X table.I tried it in following way but it is not working.

```
Drop trigger if exists myTrigger;

delimiter |
create trigger myTrigger 
after insert on X 
for each row
BEGIN
    IF STRCMP(NEW.SysLogTag,"kernel:") = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO Y(logtime,moduleid,severity,messageid,message) values(NULL,1,1,100,NEW.Message);
    ELSEIF NEW.SysLogTag like 'ntpd[%]:' THEN
        INSERT INTO Y(logtime,moduleid,severity,messageid,message) values(NULL,6,1,100,NEW.Message);
    ELSE
         INSERT INTO Y(logtime,moduleid,severity,messageid,message) values(NULL,4,1,100,NEW.Message);
    END IF;
    delete from X where ID=NEW.ID; //Not working.
END;|
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html#c8808 :

My solution was to create a unique/primary key on the table I want to insert into (in this case on S_ID), then if my sanity check fails I change the s_id to 0. This method will only ever create one duff record with an s_id of 0. Obviously you need to INSERT ignore!

```
CREATE TRIGGER sanityCheck
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF something THEN
SET NEW.S_ID = 0 ;
END IF;
END;
```